# Valid access token not work in Graph API Explorer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-oauth, facebook-access-token

The Facebook Access Token debugger say that my access token is valid:

```
Issued  1368430222 (24 minutes ago)

Expires 1373614222 (in about 2 months)

Valid   True
```

But when I test it in the Graph API Explorer it fail with this error:

```
{

  "error": {

  "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",

  "type": "OAuthException", 

  "code": 2500
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you chose the right app (that the access token was issued for) from the dropdown in the right upper corner of the GA explorer?

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you very much, CBroe